# Repeat characters in a string by the factor of an integer

Tags: java, string

Hey I need help writing a program that will take a string and stretch out the characters in it by the factor of a passed int. Let's say "Sing" is the value of out string and 2 is the value of the int. In this case the program should return SSiinngg. I'm pretty much lost but this is what I have so far. Thanks!

```
public static String nRepetitions(String s,int n){
   for(int x=1; x<=n; x++){
       }
}
```

Comment: You're very close to a simple solution. Just remember that you can `+=` to strings and you'll be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and two `for` loop

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        builder.append(s.charAt(i));

return builder.toString();
```

Slower, not recommended:

```
   String result = "";
   for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
       for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
           result += s.charAt(i);

   return result;
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to do this without StringBuilder?

Comment: @JeffSchaefer StringBuilder is fastest for String manipulation,or you can just use an emptry String , i guess.

Comment: @JeffSchaefer added another way using String

Answer (score 1):

i have edited the method to return a string, i hope to work for you:

```
public static String nRepetitions(String s,int n){
  String output="";
  for ( int x=0; x< s.length(); x++){
         for(int y = 1; y<=n; y++){
             output=output + s.charAt(x);
           }
    }
  return output;
}
```

Comment: i have updated the method, you can take a look at it.

Comment: i think it is fine now

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to use `StringBuilder` here. With `StringBuilder`, you can append characters at the end of a string. I would also consider using a nested for loop, and the `charAt()` method. Maybe something like this:

```
public static String nReps(String s, int n){
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<n; j++){
            str.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return str.toString();
}
```